# Error en laravel con metodo post

Tags: laravel

Hola me encuentro realizando un registro en laravel pero cuando le doy a un boton para que me abra la vista registro me sale el siguiente error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

El codigo de la vista es el siguiente:

```
            <form class="register-form" action="{{ url('/registrar') }}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputUsername" class="text-uppercase">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el usuario">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-uppercase">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña">
          </div>
    <div class="form-check">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-register float-right">Registrar</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

La ruta en el web.php la tengo así

```
Route::post('/registrar','registroController@RegistroCliente')->name('registro');
```

Y el codigo en mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\tbl_usuario;

class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function RegistroCliente(Request $request)
    {
        $validacion = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'usuario' => 'required|max:50',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        if($validacion->fails())
        {
            return redirect('/#register')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validacion);
        }

        $user=new tbl_usuario();
        $user->usuario=$request->usuario;
        $user->password=$request->password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ya que le estas dando un nombre a la ruta, entonces en tu form invocala de este modo: `action="{{ route('registro') }}"`, no era propiamente para *corregir* el error si no una recomendación

Comment: Esa ruta es `post`, tendrías que tener una ruta `view` o `get` para que te devuelva la vista con el formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion del error fue la siguiente, en mis rutas estaba llamando directamente desde el boton del login al controlador, entonces eso me estaba generando error, la solucion fue crear una ruta y que al oprimir el boton me redireccionara a dicha ruta:

```
Route::get('/registro',function(){
return view('registra');
})->name('prueba');
```

Y despues ya el formulario poner el action a la siguiente ruta que va al controlador

```
Route::post('/registrar','registroController@RegistroCliente')->name('registro');
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

- En el html tienes un Div sin cerrar
- En la ruta llamas a registerController pero tu controlador se llama loginController.

Comment: Tienes razon tenia mal eso, pero realice los cambios y el error sigue igual

Comment: - Puedes ejecutar en la terminal un php artisan route:list? 

- Si no sabes de que estoy hablando, ¿Puedes por favor copiar y pegar tu fichero de rutas entero? 

Otra cosa más, que sepas que laravel ya incluye autenticación más registro por defecto. 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication